# Remove whitespaces from beginning, between, end

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have the fallowing string `'   this  is my  string   '` is it possible to remove all the white spaces from the beginning and the end and just have one space between words.

To select all spaces I've used:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('   this  is my  string   ', '[ ]{2,}', '', 'g');
```

The problem with that is the two spaces between words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
trim(both ' ' from regexp_replace('    this  is my  string   ', '  +', ' ', 'g'));
```

Comment: Ah sorry, overlooked `trim`

Answer (score 3):

Use anchors.

```
SELECT regexp_replace('   this  is my  string   ', '^ +| +$|( ) +', '\1', 'g');
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/62)

- `^ +` Matches all the leading one or more spaces.
- `|` OR
- `<space>+$` Matches all the trailing spaces.
- `|` OR (ie, from the remianing string)
- `( ) +` Capture the first space and match all the following spaces.
- Replacing all the matched spaces with group index 1 will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('   this  is my  string   ', '^ +| +$| +(?= )', '', 'g');
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pI2eX2/1)

This will remove all spaces from:

1. beginning
2. end
3. Will convert multiple spaces in middle to single space

**Explanation:**

- `^ +| +$` matches spaces at beginning or at end of the string
- `+(?= )` is a positive lookahead, that matches 1 or more spaces ONLY if it is followed by at least a space
- Replacement is by empty string.